# why does outputting the variable "$size = @keys;" the numerical value 3 output?(Perl)

Tags: perl

```
my %data = (-hund => 12, -katze => 14, -maus => 16, -kuh => 18);

my @keys = keys %data;
my $size = @keys;
print "$size\n";
```

Why is the number of keys displayed when the variable `$size` is output?

Comment: You say it outputs 3 (in the title). It does not. It outputs 4.

Comment: What did you expect this code to output if not the number of keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@keys` is evaluated in scalar context (because it's being assigned to a scalar). An array evaluated in scalar context produces its number of elements.

```perl
my %data = (-hund => 12, -katze => 14, -maus => 16, -kuh => 18);

my @keys = keys %data;
my $size = @keys;         # 4
```

When `keys` is evaluated in scalar context, it produces the number of elements in the provided hash.

```perl
my $size = keys %data;    # 4
```

Since 5.26, a hash in scalar context produces the number of elements in the hash.

```perl
my $size = %data;         # 4 (5.26+)
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because scalar assignment evaluates the right hand side in **scalar context**. An array returns the number of its elements in scalar context. See [perldata](http://p3rl.org/perldata).